# Referencing a cell from another worksheet, with formula that has '+' after '='

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I have a spreadsheet that is a general summary of all cost's in my company. All i want to do is reference a cell from another work sheet so the formula for the cell is -

```
='standard cost - MP'!L61
```

However this is the value of the cell referenced -

[image]

And the formula for this cell has a '+' after the '=' which i have never seen before, so the formula for the cell 'standard cost - MP'!L61' is -

[image]

As soon as i change it, i.e. get rid of the extra plus at the beginning the value of the cell goes to 0.

And when i try and copy the cell to another worksheet it once again does not pull through the same vaolue as below. It responds with a null value again? What is that extra '+' after the '='?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks Guys

Greg

Comment: What excel version are you running? And have you got the calculations set to automatic?

Comment: Sorry for the site but i found it to be the best one, what do you see when you evaluate the formula? http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-check-for-and-evaluate-errors-in-excel-2010.html

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your resposes. glh, i used that tool and it actually helped alot. Realised there was a circular reference in one of the previous sheets. So when i removed this the whole workbook started working again. Was very odd how a circular reference stops other cells from updating/brinign through values. Cheers for all the help. Greg

Comment: I'm glad I could assist. To close the loop and help further users I've converted my comments into an answer so you can mark it if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a legacy lotus method and harmless. To further help your investigation use the **evaluate formula** functionality to assist you.

Sorry for the site but i found it to be the best one for a guide http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-check-for-and-evaluate-errors-in-excel-2010.html.